# Refreshing a single each on a click

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to display some data below 'Show click data' html element ,when a click is made.I also trying to prevent data above 'Show click data' from being refreshed.
This is close to what I want(Of course in the example when i click on some element the ajax call from the action override my the model but i don't want that)
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mobapeteco/1/

Comment: Specify the question please. I don't get what are you asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in your Route:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model:function(){

    return [
      { item:"one", display: "ONE"},
      { item:"two", display: "TWO"},
      { item:"three", display: "THREE"}
    ];
  }
});
```

Then, in your controller, you can set `displayThis` property, which would be set when you click on a list item:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions:{
    load:function(item){
      this.set('displayThis', item.display);
    }
  }
});
```

Finally, your template would look as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each model as |item|}}
      <li {{action 'load' item}}>{{item.item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>

  <h1>{{displayThis}}</h1>
</script>
```

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/yozuna/1/edit?html,js,output)